# Count Minimum number of warehouses

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given V vertices(Towns) and E edges(Routes between towns) . A company decides to build warehouses to ensure that for any town X, there will be a warehouse located either in X or in an immediately neighboring town of X.

How to find the minimum number of warehouses the company has to build.

Example: Let V=10 and E = 7 and edge pairs are :

```
1 2
2 4
2 5
3 6
8 6
9 7
10 7
```

Here answer will be 3 as its sufficient to built warehouses at Town numbers 2,6,9.

My approach:

I first count the degree of each city and then placed a warehouse in the city with maximum degree. I then marked all the adjacent cities as visited and then moved onto the next un-visited maximum node and placed a warehouse their. I did so until no un-visited is left.
Is my approach correct? Please help me on this.

Comment: Are those M pairs provided?

Comment: Yes these M pairs are given

Comment: Your approach looks good! Have you tried it? what is the problem?

Comment: Is this not a [vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Definition)?

Comment: Are there any constraints on M? Is the graph arbitrary?

Comment: please do not post questions of running contest here
http://www.hackerearth.com/jda-hackathon/algorithm/strategic-warehouse-placements/

Comment: I request moderators to close this question now.

Comment: @loannis I am sure you mean minimum vertex cover.

Comment: @Tarik Yes, just wrote vertex cover to be consistent with the title of the link I provided. The optimization problem is indeed *minimum* vertex cover.

Comment: @loannis It seems to me that PeterdeRivaz's answer is the correct one.  Minimum vertex cover seems to provide a valid solution but not necessarily optimum. Take the example of a triangle. Taking one of the vertices would do the job without having a vertex cover. What do you think? If you agree, please vote PeterdeRivaz up. He deserves it :-)

Comment: @Tarik I agree, Well-deserved +1 for Peter de Rivaz. Min vertex cover is a valid upper bound, not optimal! Interesting that the min dominating set can be recast as a set covering problem. Learned something today :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is to form a graph where:

- The vertices are the towns
- An edge exists between two vertices iff there is a direct route between the corresponding towns.

Then find the [minimal dominating set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) for this graph.  You should build a warehouse in each town corresponding to the vertices in the minimal dominating set.

Unfortunately, the dominating set problem is NP-complete so finding the exact minimum is hard, but your greedy algorithm should give a good approximation.

Comment: I request moderators to close this question now as the question is of running contest problem.

Comment: @Prashant Seriously, if the contestants have Internet access, you must find another way to police them. I had a hand on programming session for a interview candidate. He was provided with problems to solve on a PC with no Internet access.

Comment: @Tarik so it's right according to you to ask running contests questions on SO?

Comment: if i could, i must have already closed this question
moderators should see this

Comment: @Prashant it is perhaps not *ethical* to ask a question about an on-going contest but it is not *illegal*. Big difference.